# emacs configure file reports Wrong type argument

Tags: emacs, elisp

```
(custom-set-variables

 '(cua-mode t nil (cua-base))
 '(text-mode-hook (quote (turn-on-auto-fill text-mode-hook-identify))))
(custom-set-faces

;;Auto-Complete

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins")

(require 'auto-complete-config)

(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/plugins/ac-dict")

(ac-config-default)

;;YASnippet 

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")

(require 'yasnippet)

(yas-global-mode 1)

(yas/load-directory "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet/snippets")


;;iBus

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/ibus-el-0.3.2")

(require 'ibus)

(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'ibus-mode-on)

)
```

this is my .emacs file. I am not a lisp guy, but i wanna make emacs easier to use. But now it reports

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading
>   `/home/city/.emacs':
>
> Wrong type argument: symbolp, ~/.emacs.d/plugins

i have no idea why it does not work. hope you great guy would help me. 
Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you could comment out different segments of your config and try loading it again in order to narrow down what part produces the error.

Comment: @JamesPorter， i have edited this file. and I think there is something wrong when load-path. but I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your problem

Your problem is that you did not close the paren at the end of the `(custom-set-faces` line.
This means that the values of `add-to-list` forms are passed as arguments to `custom-set-faces`.

### How to debug `.emacs`

1. Start with indenting the whole file (<kbd>C-home C-end C-M-\</kbd>).
   If some lines shift, you have extra or missing parens.
   (In general, lispers do *not* count parens - they look at the indentation).
2. Use the binary search (removing half the forms and restarting emacs).